# Predictive model: conditional missing values

Tags: predictive-models, missing-data

I have a dataset in which some values are missing because only the are to be filled only if some other variable has a certain value.

How should I treat this values when building a predictive model? classical algorithms would drop the entire observation in presence of such cases.

I thought about using a custom value eg "not required" for categorical variables, but I don't know what to do in case of continuous variables.

Thanks